# MySQL Comparison with Count

Tags: mysql, comparison

I'm trying to update the active field and set it based on how many products have shipped to the customer.  But it's not working as intended. I have some records which issueShipped is greater than totalIssues but isActive isn't being set to false.

```
UPDATE xatm.subscriptions a, 
       (SELECT idSubscription, COUNT(idProduct) issueShipped 
        FROM xatm.subscriptionshipments 
        group by idSubscription) b 
SET a.isActive = (a.totalIssues > b.issueShipped)
WHERE a.idsubscriptions = b.idSubscription
AND a.isComp = 0 AND a.isReoccurring = 0;
```

Comment: My feeling is that your query is correct.  Can you include some data which illustrates the problem you are having?

Answer (score 1):

I actually think your current query should work, but in any case an alternative you could try would be an update join:

```
UPDATE xatm.subscriptions a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT idSubscription, COUNT(idProduct) issueShipped 
    FROM xatm.subscriptionshipments 
    GROUP BY idSubscription
) b
    ON a.idsubscriptions = b.idSubscription
SET a.isActive = (a.totalIssues > b.issueShipped)
WHERE 
    a.isComp = 0 AND
    a.isReoccurring = 0;
```